# How to remove all of the duplicates from the table?

Tags: mysql

I have the following data in my database

I have got some duplicate records while inserting data .

```
CREATE TABLE `historical_data` (
  `symbol_name` varchar(70) DEFAULT NULL,
  `current_day` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `open_val` varchar(50) 
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ;

Insert Into historical_data values('SBIN','10-DEC-2015','300.10');
Insert Into historical_data values('SBIN','10-DEC-2015','300.10');
Insert Into historical_data values('SBIN','10-DEC-2015','300.10');
Insert Into historical_data values('ACC','10-DEC-2015','1233.10');
Insert Into historical_data values('TATELXSI','10-DEC-2015','1980.10');
```

Could you please let me know how to remove all the duplicates from the table

Duplicate means  **same symbol and same current day**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70d96

Comment: Duplicates meaning having the same values for all `symbol_name`,`current_day`,`open_val` in the same row, or just a duplicate value within any of these columns?

Comment: @hd having the same values for all symbol_name,current_day,open_val in the same row , for example SBIN has got two duplicate values and i need to remove 2 of them .

Comment: You can consider duplicate as same symbol and same current day .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to do so. Just run this query as it is:-

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE `historical_data`
ADD UNIQUE INDEX (`symbol_name`, `current_day`, `open_val` );
```

This will add unique index to your table and remove all dulicate rows and will make sure that no duplicate rows being inserted in future.

Answer (score 0):

You can write down a `STORED PROCEDURE` to read every row using `CURSOR` and to run a loop to find out any similar row, and if found, you just need to `DELETE` that particular row.

Comment: Generally, an answer offers the solution and not just hints.

Comment: Excellent people needs a guidance, rest are spoon feeders.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a primary key to table, so that you can differentiate duplicates without using cursors and then delete them by joining table onto itself:

```
ALTER TABLE historical_data ADD COLUMN `id` int auto_increment primary key not null;
DELETE from historical_data AS hd
    LEFT JOIN historical_data hd1 ON
    hd1.symbol_name=hd.symbol_name AND hd1.current_day=hd.current_day  
    AND hd1.id < hd.id
WHERE hd1.id is NOT NULL
```

or use a unique index:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE historical_data ADD UNIQUE INDEX unique_index_on_symbol_name_and_day (symbol_name,current_day);
```

Comment: i dont have any primary key and cannot add it also .

Comment: Then try adding unique index (see example in answer)